# GUI not updating with current information even though the correct Events are firing

Tags: java, swing, swingworker, jprogressbar, tablecellrenderer

I am having a slight problem with a GUI where the *ProgressCellRenderer* is not updating until I either click on it or highlight it or even resize the window. I have slimmed down the code to just use generic data and using sleeps to emulate a long running task.

What have I missed that is causing it to not update until I cause an update on the gui itself?

This is minimum working code that will run.

```
 public class Test
    {

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            new Test();
        }

        public Test()
        {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    try
                    {
                        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                    }
                    catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex)
                    {
                    }

                    UpdatableTableModel model = new UpdatableTableModel();

                    JTable table = new JTable();
                    table.setModel(model);

                    table.getColumn("Status").setCellRenderer(new ProgressCellRender());

                    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                    frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);

                    StringFinderWorker worker = new StringFinderWorker(model);
                    worker.execute();

                }
            });
        }

        public class ProgressCellRender extends JProgressBar implements TableCellRenderer
        {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column)
            {
                int progress = 0;
                if (value instanceof Float)
                {
                    progress = Math.round(((Float) value) * 100f);
                }
                else if (value instanceof Integer)
                {
                    progress = (int) value;
                }
                setValue(progress);
                return this;
            }
        }

        public class RowData
        {
            private String string;
            private float status;

            public RowData(String string)
            {
                this.string = string;
                this.status = 0f;
            }

            public String getString()
            {
                return string;
            }

            public float getStatus()
            {
                return status;
            }

            public void setStatus(float status)
            {
                this.status = status;
            }
        }

        public class UpdatableTableModel extends AbstractTableModel
        {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            private List<RowData> rows;
            private Map<String, RowData> mapLookup;

            public UpdatableTableModel()
            {
                rows = new ArrayList<>(25);
                mapLookup = new HashMap<>(25);
            }

            @Override
            public int getRowCount()
            {
                return rows.size();
            }

            @Override
            public int getColumnCount()
            {
                return 2;
            }

            @Override
            public String getColumnName(int column)
            {
                String name = "??";
                switch (column)
                {
                    case 0:
                        name = "The String";
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        name = "Status";
                        break;
                }
                return name;
            }

            @Override
            public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex)
            {
                RowData rowData = rows.get(rowIndex);
                Object value = null;
                switch (columnIndex)
                {
                    case 0:
                        value = rowData.getString();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        value = rowData.getStatus();
                        break;
                }
                return value;
            }

            @Override
            public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex)
            {
                RowData rowData = rows.get(rowIndex);
                switch (columnIndex)
                {
                    case 3:
                        if (aValue instanceof Float)
                        {
                            rowData.setStatus((float) aValue);
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }

            public void addString(String string)
            {
                RowData rowData = new RowData(string);
                mapLookup.put(string, rowData);
                rows.add(rowData);
                fireTableRowsInserted(rows.size() - 1, rows.size() - 1);
            }

            protected void updateStatus(String string, int progress)
            {
                RowData rowData = mapLookup.get(string);
                if (rowData != null)
                {
                    int row = rows.indexOf(rowData);
                    float p = (float) progress / 100f;
                    setValueAt(p, row, 3);
                    fireTableCellUpdated(row, 3);
                }
            }
        }

        public class StringFinderWorker extends SwingWorker<List<String>, String>
        {

            private UpdatableTableModel model;

            public StringFinderWorker(UpdatableTableModel model)
            {
                this.model = model;
            }

            @Override
            protected void process(List<String> chunks)
            {
                for (String string : chunks)
                {
                    model.addString(string);
                }
            }

            protected ArrayList<String> getStrings()
            {
                ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
                {
                    strings.add("test: " + i);
                }
                return strings;
            }

            @Override
            protected List<String> doInBackground() throws Exception
            {
                List<String> strings = getStrings();

                for (int i = 0; i < strings.size(); i++)
                {
                    publish(strings.get(i));
                }
                return strings;
            }

            @Override
            protected void done()
            {
                try
                {
                    List<String> strings = get();
                    for (String string : strings)
                    {
                        new StringDownloaderWorker(model, string).execute();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception exp)
                {
                    exp.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        public class StringDownloaderWorker extends SwingWorker<String, String>
        {

            private String currentString;
            private UpdatableTableModel model;

            public StringDownloaderWorker(UpdatableTableModel model, String string)
            {
                this.currentString = string;
                this.model = model;

                addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt)
                    {
                        if (evt.getPropertyName().equals("progress"))
                        {
                            StringDownloaderWorker.this.model.updateStatus(currentString, (int) evt.getNewValue());
                        }
                    }
                });

            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground() throws Exception
            {
                for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
                {
                    setProgress(i);
                    try
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException ie)
                    {
                        //
                    }
                }

                return currentString;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to kick yourself when you see this...

The column indexes that you are using to register the fact that the cell has changed are wrong...

You are using `setValueAt(p, row, 3);`, when the progress column is actually `1`, so you should actually be using `setValueAt(p, row, 1);`

This also means that the `switch` statement in your `setValueAt` method will need to change.

```
@Override
public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    RowData rowData = rows.get(rowIndex);
    switch (columnIndex) {
        case 1:
            if (aValue instanceof Float) {
                rowData.setStatus((float) aValue);
                fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, columnIndex);
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

You will also note that I moved the `fireTableCellUpdated` call to this method, as you never know when `setValueAt` might be called.

Comment: Selected this as the correct answer due to it fixing the underlying error and not hiding it. definitely kicked myself :P

Comment: @user3045798 I've done this so many times, I've lost count :P

Answer (score 0):

you must Update your table every time when there is a change

i mean when there is some change on your table then you must call your Update Function to update the table

to do that you can  use a listener to detect some change ; if there is a change in one cell or more then you must call the function to update the table

generally to achieve such update you must work with your model input because every time when your table have some change in one or more cells ===> that s mean the model of your table is change

update the model then call the main function to Update your container of the current window 
ther is three functions  for updating an interface SWING for exemple : update function or repaint function or setContentPane(your Jpanel or Container of the table )

Comment: So, you mean like, when the OP calls `fireTableCellUpdated(row, 3);`  in their `updateStatus` method?  Sure, it probably should be in the `setValueAt` method, but the event trigger method is been called...this isn't the problem...sorry...

Comment: Due to the post of @MadProgrammer, I have decided that his answer is more correct due to the fact that it fixes the problem and not hides it like this does even though this does "work"